# Prime number check in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Could anyone help me on how to check whether a number is prime using `for` loop?

Comment: We can help you getting started, but giving away answer won't help you learn.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee No need to be rude to the OP.  He/she may be a high schooler looking for help.  StackOverflow Community is working hard to keep experienced programmers from demeaning newcomers.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 4):

From [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/) site.

We learned numbers are prime if the only divisors they have are 1 and itself. Trivially, we can check every integer from 1 to itself (exclusive) and test whether it divides evenly.

For example, one might be tempted to run this algorithm:

```
//checks whether an int is prime or not.
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

This doesn't seem bad at first, but we can make it faster - much faster. Consider that if 2 divides some integer n, then (n/2) divides n as well. This tells us we don't have to try out all integers from 2 to n. Now we can modify our algorithm:

```
//checks whether an int is prime or not.
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; 2 * i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

With some more efficient coding, we notice that you really only have to go up to the square root of n, because if you list out all of the factors of a number, the square root will always be in the middle (if it happens to not be an integer, we're still ok, we just might over-approximate, but our code will still work).

Finally, we know 2 is the "oddest" prime - it happens to be the only even prime number. Because of this, we need only check 2 separately, then traverse odd numbers up to the square root of n. In the end, our code will resemble this:

```
//checks whether an int is prime or not.
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, we've gone from checking every integer (up to n to find out that a number is prime) to just checking half of the integers up to the square root (the odd ones, really). This is a huge improvement, especially considering when numbers are large.

Comment: this would actually fail for 1, 2 and negative numbers

Comment: Can you correct the code. ? It fails for 1,2 and negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Simple Programme to Check Whether a Number is Prime or Not ;

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int count=0;
    System.out.print("Input a Number : ");
    int num=input.nextInt();
    for(int i=2;i<num;i++){
        if(num%i==0){count++;}
    }
    if(num>1&count==0){
        System.out.print("\nIt Is a Prime Number.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("\nIt Is a Not Prime Number.");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to read @Neng Liu's answer from up to bottom and try to understand all the algorithms.
However, You can check this code for second algorithm from @Neng Liu's answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrimeNumber{
    public static void main(String [] args){
       int number,i,rem;
       boolean flag = true;
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter an integer to check if its PRIME number : ");
       number = input.nextInt();
       if(number >= 2){
           for(i = 2; 2 * i < number; i++){
               rem = number % i;
               if(rem == 0){
                   flag = false;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if(flag){
               System.out.println(number+" is a Prime number");
           }else{
               System.out.println(number+" is not Prime number");
           }
       }else{
           System.out.println("1 & Negative numbers can't be prime ! ");
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested for all prime numbers between a range like 0 to 10,000